# Does `strace -f` work differently when run inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, process, strace

Assume the following:

- I have a program `myprogram` inside a docker container
- I'm running the docker container with

  `docker run --privileged=true my-label/my-container`
- Inside the container - the program is being run with:

  `strace -f -e trace=desc ./myprogram`

What I see is that the `strace` (despite having the `-f` on) doesn't follow all the child processes.

I see the following output from `strace`

```
[pid    10] 07:36:46.668931 write(2, "..\n"..., 454 <unfinished ...>

<stdout of ..>

<stdout other output - but I don't see the write commands - so probably from a child process>

[pid    10] 07:36:46.669684 write(2, "My final output\n", 24 <unfinished ...>

<stdout of My final output>
```

What I want to see is the other `write` commands.

Now I should see the the other `write` commands - because I'm using `-f`.

What I think is happening is that running inside docker makes the process handling and security different.

My question is: **Does `strace -f` work differently when run inside a docker container?**

Note that this application starts and stops in 2 seconds - so the tracing tool has to follow the application lifecycle - like `strace` does. Connecting to a server background process won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `strace` truncates string output - you have to explicitly tell it that you want more than the first n (10?) string chars. You do this with `-s 800`.

```
strace -s 800 -ff  ./myprogram
```

You can also get all the `write` commands by asking `strace` explicitly with `-e write`.

```
strace -s 800 -ff -e write  ./myprogram
```